# How do you find missing number in list?

Tags: prolog

Say I have a List [1,2,4,5], I would like to have a predicate that returns 3 as the missing element. You can assuming that the input list is always sorted sequentially.

My solution so far:

```
% missing_number/2 (ListToBeChecked, ListToBeCompared, MissingNum)
missing_number([], [], []) :- !.
missing_number([Head | Tail], [Head | Rest], Number) :- 
    missing_number(Tail, Rest, Number).
missing_number(_, [X | _], [X | Node]) :- 
    missing_number(_, _, Number), !.
```

Comment: Isn't a predicate something that returns true or false..?

Comment: you obviously don't use prolog.

Comment: @arasmussen: in Prolog, there are no functions, only predicates "returning" values through unification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `between/3` to generate all numbers from min to max. Use `memberchk/2` (or `member/2`) to find the missing ones.

```
L = [1,2,4,5],
L = [M|_],
last(L, N),
between(M, N, I),
\+ memberchk(I, L).
```

Exercise for the reader: wrap this up in a predicate.

**EDIT** Efficient solution, by popular request:

```
missing([I,K|_], M) :-
    I1 is I+1,
    K1 is K-1,
    between(I1, K1, M).
missing([_|Ns], M) :-
    missing(Ns, M).
```

**EDIT 2**: More elegant version of the above, inspired by @chac, not necessarily very efficient:

```
missing(L,M) :- append(_, [I,J|_], L), I1 is I+1, J1 is J-1, between(I1,J1,M).
```

Comment: and you run through the list lots of times while 1 run is needed... ;(

Comment: @Mog: the OP did not ask for an *efficient* solution ;) This is just the short solution.

Comment: The solution works, but what about an efficient solution? I made my own solution perhaps you would like to have a look?

Comment: sure, you should have added it to the OP

Comment: No DCGs? `missing(L,M) :- phrase((...,[I,J],{I+1<J,between(I,J,M)},...),L).`

Comment: @false: I must admin I'm less of a DCG fan than maybe I should be ;)

Comment: Succumb to the graphical appeal!

Comment: @larsmans: I always have doubts about using `append/3` when I need to write efficient code. My tests say that your first efficient version is about twice as fast as your second (list of one million numbers, penultimate number missing).

Comment: @twinterer: I'll add a note to the answer concerning the third version's efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

The paradigmatic predicate append/3 many times can help in duties involving lists: here suffice to check for consecutive elements that aren't successors:

```
missing(L, M) :-
    append(_, [A,B|_], L),
    \+ succ(A, B), succ(A, M).
```

**Completed**

To be able to fulfill gaps of length > 1, the solution ends up almost identical to the larsman one:

```
missing(L, M) :-
    append(_, [A,B|_], L),
    succ(A, S), succ(P, B), between(S, P, M).
```

succ/2 allows a more declarative approach, but it's noticeably slower than arithmetic.

Comment: Bug: `M` is a singleton variable in this program.

Comment: Now it returns false positives, if I replace the last `,` with a `.`

Comment: Just to note, it's correct now. I was editing inline and hit submit too early.

Comment: It's still not correct. `missing([0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 9], M).` skips `M=3`.

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't work for unsorted lists

```
missing([], []).
missing([H|T], R) :- missing([H|T], H, R).
missing([], _I, []).
missing([H|T], I, [I|R]) :-
    H =\= I,
    !,
    NextI is I + 1,
    missing([H|T], NextI, R).
missing([_|T], I, R) :-
    NextI is I + 1,
    missing(T, NextI, R).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
missing([], []).
missing([H|T], R) :- missing([H|T], H, R).
missing([], _I, []).
missing([H|T], I, [I|R]) :-
    H =\= I,
    !,
    NextI is I + 1,
    missing([H|T], NextI, R).
missing([_|T], I, R) :-
    NextI is I + 1,
    missing(T, NextI, R).
```

for the no helper predicate one.

Comment: well, it's longer but actually simpler to understand from my point of vue, matter of taste I guess :)

Comment: Doesn't work either, except on non-empty lists without missing elements :p

Comment: that's the risk of the non test thingy :D I'll check it after my reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below: 
The implementation is in JavaScript. But the algorithm can be converted. I hope this helps!
The assumption is that the list is ascending and is an arithmetric series - n, n+1, n+2... Additionally, the list can start anywhere, not just at 0

```
    function getMissingNum() {
    var start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150) / 1;
    var nElem = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) / 1;
    var set = [];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * nElem) + start / 1;
    for (var i = start; i <= start + nElem; i++) {
        //skip one number randomly
        if (i == rand) continue;
        set.push(i);
    }

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        sum += set[i];
    }

    // SEE HERE: 
    // Total = N * (N + 1) / 2
    var max = set[set.length - 1];
    var min = set[0];// - 1;
    var actual = (((max * (max + 1)) / 2));
    var excluded = (((min * (min + 1)) / 2));
    var missing = actual - excluded - sum + start;
    if (min > start) {
        missing = missing + min;
    }
    return {
        missing: missing,
        min: min,
        max: max,
        actual: actual,
        excluded: excluded,
        rand: rand,
        start: start,
        nElem: nElem
    }
}

var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var result = getMissingNum();
    if (result.rand != result.missing) {
        results.push(result);
    }
}
```